# Authenticating .NET running in Docker container in GCP Compute Engine

Tags: .net, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am really struggling with this. I have read so much documentation over the last day or so and cannot work it out.

I cannot find examples!

I had a .NET app which I had running happily in Cloud Run. it was accessing Google Cloud services, no problem. It was using the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0` image and being deployed by Cloud Build on a trigger from GitHub. The app was authenticated locally using Application Default Credentials, and those rights made it to the Docker container somehow. No idea.

Turns out, Cloud Run is not the right architecture since it is a long-running process. So I decided to switch to a Compute Engine instance. Now, it seems ADC does not work in the same way: at least, my app is not able to authenticate. So I'd like to know what my options are. As I say, I have done a lot of reading and still am not really clear!

- can ADC be used by a Docker container in an CE instance? If so, what is the procedure? Are there any examples anywhere?
- failing that, how do I get my Docker container to expose a key file from the VM environment? I certainly do not want the key file to be in the repo

What other options do I have?

Comment: ADC is a method of finding credentials. Do you want to use a service account JSON key file or the Compute Engine metadata server for credentials? For the first case, use a Docker volume mount to map the JSON key file inside the container and set the environment variable inside the container GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. For the second case, IIRC, change the Docker network to `--network=host` and the container will use the default credentials assigned to the VM.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. The first seems more straightforward, the second more...dunno. "Correct"? I'll try both. 

Comment: Turns out, auth was working after all. I spent four hours screaming at my computer configuring both of those options. But I was just using the wrong service account.